# CollectionView takes a while to appear

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using autolayout anchors to place my `collectionView` in my view. In my `collectionView`, I have a list of users. Since the number of cells is not definite, the height is changed based on the height of the content inside the `collectionView`. This is what have:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let contentViewHeight = collectionView.getContentHeight() // Returns height of the content of the collectionView

    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentViewHeight).isActive = true

    // I create a height constraint based on the contentHeight

    self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

This code works great, but the only side-effect is that my `collectionView` loads in a bit late when the view is shown. Everything else in the view is loaded, and the `collectionView` just pops up after a while. Is there any way I can add my constraint without causing this issue?

I tried moving my code to `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, but the anchor isn't even applied.

Comment: You could try putting your code in viewDidLayoutSubviews which should be called once the collectionView knows its height, but before the view appears? Alternatively you could factor in the slight delay by showing an activity indicator in the place of the collectionView until its ready, then fade it in nicely?

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` doesn't seem to work. So adding an activity indicator seems like my best bet. @MikeAtkins-Spelling